# Let $H$ be a $\sigma-$compact subgroup of locally compact abelian group $G$ such that $G/H$ is $\sigma-$compact. Is $G$ $\sigma-$compact?

Tags: topological-groups

Let $H$ be a $\sigma-$compact, closed subgroup of locally compact abelian group $G$ such that $G/H$ is $\sigma-$compact. Is $G$ $\sigma-$compact?

Comment: Yes. first note that Every closed subspace of a locally compact space is locally compact and If $G$ is locally compact then $G/H$ is locally compact. now use this theorem: If both $H$ and $G/H$ are locally compact and $σ$-compact then $G$ is locally compact and $σ$-compact.